# Type Eroor :message_str.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

My message_str contains the buffer of HexaDecimal value and i'm trying to split string into array.

```
function mqtt_messsageReceived(topic, message_str, packet) 
{
    console.log("message to string", message_str);
    insert_message(topic, message_str, packet);
};
function insert_message(topic, message_str, packet) 
{
    var message_arr = extract_string(message_str); //split a string into an array
    console.log(message_arr);
};  
function extract_string(message_str) 
{
var message_arr = message_str.split(" "); //convert to array    
return message_arr;
};
```

I want output like this,
[86,a1,76,a7,31,...][message_str is shown in image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmFv.png)

Comment: Sounds like `message_str` is not a string.

Comment: It is a buffer of HexaDecimal value which is store into message_str variable.That value is coming from MQTT Broker

var mqtt = require('mqtt'); 
var Topic = '/test'; //subscribe to test topic
var Broker_URL = 'mqtt:// broker.hivemq.com';

var client  = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL, options);
client.on('message', mqtt_messsageReceived);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
var message_arr = message_str.split(" ");
```

with

```
var message_arr =message_str.toString('hex').match(/.{1,2}/g);
```

enjoy :)